# Trying to launch a script from a script, as a different user

Tags: powershell

I've been banging my head against a wall for far too long on this issue.
I'm attempting to launch a script from a GUI script. The idea is that a user will use their non-admin account, and have the script pass off their admin credentials to a script that does the actual work.

I've tried to use Invoke-Command and Start-Process with little to no success. I can either get the script to launch as admin, or pass parameters, but not both. The idea is that I collect a bunch of information about a user (name, job title, phone number etc) in a GUI form and pass those off to a script that will create a new account for that user.

I've tried the following lines to get this to pass off correctly, but I think I need way more eyes on the problem.

```
Invoke-Command -Credential { .\create-newuser.ps1 -givenname $Givenname -Surname $Surname } -Computername 'LocalHost'
#Many parameters excluded for simplicity.
```

And

```
Start-Process -filename pwsh -argumentlist ".\create-newuser.ps1 -Givenname $Givenname -Surname $Surname" -Credential $Creds
#Many parameters excluded for simplicity
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't elevate the process and also impersonate at the same time. The workaround that would likely work is using `Invoke-Command` but instead of invoking to your localhost, invoke to a remote host

Comment: I don't actually need the script to run with administrative rights, I just need it to run with the users admin credentials. Most of the work is done with the AD Suite of tools, which allows credentials passing, but I also need to set ACL permissions which does not allow credentials to be passed.